# Change git root folder

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have used the Github desktop application to manage my Github repository. I have the following folder structure:

```
myRepo/
    config/
    mappings/
    src/
    bin/
    eclipse/
    lib/
    README.md
    LICENSE.md
```

How would I go about making `src` the main folder of my repository so it will only commit files inside `src` while retaining the files `README.md` and `LICENSE.md` while still having the files inside `src` inside the `src` folder, like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should ignore folder other than `src`.

### .gitignore

```
### project ###
config
mappings
bin
eclipse
lib

### Eclipse ###
.project
.metadata
.classpath
.settings/
```

Read more:

- https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Use tools:

- http://gitignore.io/

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `.gitignore`.